# How to "unset" injectableValues from objectMapper?

Tags: java, jackson, mapper, constructor-injection

i am using injectableValues to deserealize a json. I am doing this like:

```
    final InjectableValues.Std injectableValues = new InjectableValues.Std();
    injectableValues.addValue(HttpRestResponse.class, response);
    emailsResponse = this.prepareCustomMapper().reader(EmailsResponse.class).withInjectableValues(injectableValues)
        .readValue(response.getBody());
```

---

```
protected ObjectMapper prepareCustomMapper() {
    if (this.mapper == null) {
        this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        this.mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        this.mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
    }
    return this.mapper;
}
```

So, this works fine. My problem is that when i don't want to inject values i do it like this:

```
EmailResponse emailResponse = this.prepareCustomMapper().readValue(response.getBody(), EmailResponse.class);
```

And this time, i am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No 'injectableValues' configured, can not inject value with id [com.despegar.cross.commons.utils.restutils.HttpRestResponse]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.findInjectableValue(StdDeserializationContext.java:101)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.impl.PropertyValueBuffer.inject(PropertyValueBuffer.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.impl.PropertyBasedCreator.startBuilding(PropertyBasedCreator.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializer.java:739)
```

this is my EmailResponse.class constructors:

```
// I use this one if i want to inject HttpRestResponseObject 
public EmailResponse(@JacksonInject final HttpRestResponse request) {
    super();
    this.request = request
}

public EmailResponse() {
    super();
}
```

So, my conclusion was that injectable value that i setted at first objectMapper's mapping , persists at second objectMapper's mapping, and it is trying to inject value to a constructor that no recieves it. 
I tried putting into prepareCustomMapper() this, so by this way i thought that it would "clean" injectedValues everytime that was called:

```
this.mapper.setInjectableValues(null);
```

But this didn't work neither.

Do you know how to "unset" injectableValues? or how to pass injectableValues for the current mapping that woldn't persists in the future. Thanks from now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject 'null' value:

```
final InjectableValues.Std injectableValues = new InjectableValues.Std();
    injectableValues.addValue(HttpRestResponse.class, null);
    emailsResponse = this.prepareCustomMapper().reader(EmailsResponse.class).withInjectableValues(injectableValues)
        .readValue(response.getBody());
```